# How to check for an non empty element field?

Tags: craft3

Which one of the following is the correct of way of checking if an element field like images, entries or category is not empty?

1. {% if entry.fieldHandle.one() %}
2. {% if entry.fieldHandle.all() %}
3. {% if entry.fieldHandle.count() %}
4. {% if entry.fieldHandle | length %}
5. {% if entry.fieldHandle.exists() %}
6. {% if entry.fieldHandle %}

Answer (score 2):

They'll all work except for the last one:

```
entry.fieldHandle.one()
entry.fieldHandle.all()
entry.fieldHandle.count()
entry.fieldHandle | length
entry.fieldHandle.exists()
```